# SQL query to filter columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question regarding the SQL query.
I have this table shown below

| Region | Rep | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Quebec | Jones | Pencil |
| Ontario | Kivell | Binder |
| Ontario | Jardine | Pencil |
| Ontario | Gill | Pen |
| Alberta | Sorvino | Pencil |
| Quebec | Jones | Binder |
| Ontario | Andrews | Pencil |
| Ontario | Jardine | Pencil |
| Alberta | Thompson | Pencil |
| Quebec | Jones | Binder |
| Ontario | Morgan | Pencil |
| Quebec | Howard | Binder |
| Alberta | Sorvino | Pen |
| Alberta | Thompson | Binder |
| Ontario | Andrews | Pencil |
| Ontario | Jardine | Binder |
| Ontario | Jardine | Binder |
| Ontario | Andrews | Binder |

I have to filter for each Region then for each Rep and lastly for each Item.
So like one example of a table should look like this:

| Region | Rep | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Quebec | Jones | Pencil |

And then I have to go back and choose(filter) the other item and the table should look like this:

| Region | Rep | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Quebec | Jones | Binder |
| Quebec | Jones | Binder |

After I copied these two tables I have to go back to Rep and chose the other value and again filter **item column** again the same to get the tables.
After I am done with all Rep and Item I have to go back and choose another Region and repeat the same steps

How can I achieve this with a query?

Comment: Please don’t link to images in your question - add all information as editable text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your task, you need few different queries (please, replace `table_name` with yours):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `Region` LIKE 'Quebec' 
    AND `Rep ` LIKE 'Jones' 
    AND `Item` LIKE 'Pencil'
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `Region` LIKE 'Quebec' 
    AND `Rep ` LIKE 'Jones' 
    AND `Item` LIKE 'Binder'
```

Comment: Yes this is what I have to do but I have to do it for each Region, for each Rep, and for each Item. So it has to be dynamic.

Comment: So, that should be multiple different queries. In this case, you need to use some programming language to select the list and display it separately. Or that should be some complex SQL request with loop and some other logic to display the result. However, in the second case I do not really understand the expected result – should it be one united table or something else.

Comment: No, they have to be separated tables. How can I do it with a list? How should I pass the parameters to the query using list?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The results for a query have no physical existence - once you run one query (in the same client/UI) the results of the previous query are lost. So having the results of multiple queries available makes no sense - if that's what you are asking? Or are you proposing to write the result from each query to its own table? Please could you clarify what the end result is that you are trying to achieve?